# Query working on SqlDeveloper but not in php.. Why?

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

Im trying to make a query to get a historic from my database. In SqlDeveloper the query is working perfectly but not in php. If I dump the `executeQueries` it returns me "bool(false)". The parameters are good. I just do not understand why.

The query :

```
 $sQuery = "SELECT * from (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dep.DATE_DEPOT_DECLA desc) AS numLigne,pub.LIB_TITRE , contrat.id_contrat,
        NVL(dp.NUM_PARUTION_DECLA,dp.NUM_PARUTION_CONST) ,dep.id_depot, dep.DATE_DEPOT_DECLA,
        sum(decode(id_lib_prep,'50003', round(nb_ex_fac,0),nb_ex_decla)) AS NB_EX_DECLA,
        sum(decode(id_lib_prep,'50001', nb_ex_fac,0)) AS NB_EX_QL,
        sum(decode(id_lib_prep,'50002', nb_ex_fac,0)) AS NB_EX_CP, 
        sum(decode(id_lib_prep,'50003', round(nb_ex_fac,0),0)) AS NB_EX_PEM,
        sum(decode(id_lib_prep,'50004', nb_ex_fac,0)) AS NB_EX_LAT,
        sum(decode(id_lib_prep,'50005', nb_ex_fac,0)) AS NB_EX_ATTF,
        sum(decode(id_lib_prep,'50006', nb_ex_fac,0)) AS NB_EX_PIC,
        sum(decode(id_lib_prep,'50003', 0, nb_ex_fac)) AS TOTAL_EX_HORSPEM,
        (select sum(mt_tot_ttc) from depot_facturation where dep.id_depot = depot_facturation.id_depot) AS MT_FAC,
        drl.STATUT_DEPOT

        FROM depot_publication dp
        INNER JOIN depot_preparation dpre ON dpre.ID_depot = dp.ID_depot
        INNER JOIN DEPOT dep ON dep.id_depot =dpre.ID_depot
        inner join depot_drl drl on drl.ID_DEPOT=dep.id_depot
        INNER JOIN MERIDIEN_CONTRAT contrat ON (DP.NUM_CONTRAT_DECLA=contrat.ID_CONTRAT)
        INNER JOIN MERIDIEN_PUBLICATION pub ON (contrat.ID_PUBLICATION=pub.ID_PUBLICATION)
        WHERE
        contrat.ID_CONTRAT = :0 and dep.DATE_DEPOT_DECLA < to_date( :1 ,'YYYY/MM/DD')

        GROUP BY
        pub.LIB_TITRE,
        contrat.id_contrat,
        NVL(dp.NUM_PARUTION_DECLA,dp.NUM_PARUTION_CONST),
        dep.id_depot,
        dep.DATE_DEPOT_DECLA,
        drl.STATUT_DEPOT
        ORDER BY dep.DATE_DEPOT_DECLA DESC,NVL(dp.NUM_PARUTION_DECLA,dp.NUM_PARUTION_CONST) DESC
    ) where numLigne <=30;
    ";


    $toto = $this->executeQueries($sQuery, array($idContrat,$dateDecla));
    $aResultSet = $this->getAllRows();
    var_dump($toto);
```

UPDATE :

I got this error in my log : `'ORA-01830: Le mod�le  du format de date se termine avant la conversion de la cha�ne d\'entr�e enti�re',`

Comment: What framework do you use?

Comment: Okay i found it, the error come from the date -> `dep.DATE_DEPOT_DECLA < to_date( :1 ,'YYYY/MM/DD')`, it was the wrong format.

Comment: Im using Zend by the way

Answer (score 0):

Missing inverted commas, Try this one.

```
   $sQuery = "SELECT * from (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dep.DATE_DEPOT_DECLA desc) AS numLigne,pub.LIB_TITRE , contrat.id_contrat,
    NVL(dp.NUM_PARUTION_DECLA,dp.NUM_PARUTION_CONST) ,dep.id_depot, dep.DATE_DEPOT_DECLA,
    sum(decode(id_lib_prep,'50003', round(nb_ex_fac,0),nb_ex_decla)) AS NB_EX_DECLA,
    sum(decode(id_lib_prep,'50001', nb_ex_fac,0)) AS NB_EX_QL,
    sum(decode(id_lib_prep,'50002', nb_ex_fac,0)) AS NB_EX_CP, 
    sum(decode(id_lib_prep,'50003', round(nb_ex_fac,0),0)) AS NB_EX_PEM,
    sum(decode(id_lib_prep,'50004', nb_ex_fac,0)) AS NB_EX_LAT,
    sum(decode(id_lib_prep,'50005', nb_ex_fac,0)) AS NB_EX_ATTF,
    sum(decode(id_lib_prep,'50006', nb_ex_fac,0)) AS NB_EX_PIC,
    sum(decode(id_lib_prep,'50003', 0, nb_ex_fac)) AS TOTAL_EX_HORSPEM,
    (select sum(mt_tot_ttc) from depot_facturation where dep.id_depot = depot_facturation.id_depot) AS MT_FAC,
    drl.STATUT_DEPOT

    FROM depot_publication dp
    INNER JOIN depot_preparation dpre ON dpre.ID_depot = dp.ID_depot
    INNER JOIN DEPOT dep ON dep.id_depot =dpre.ID_depot
    inner join depot_drl drl on drl.ID_DEPOT=dep.id_depot
    INNER JOIN MERIDIEN_CONTRAT contrat ON (DP.NUM_CONTRAT_DECLA=contrat.ID_CONTRAT)
    INNER JOIN MERIDIEN_PUBLICATION pub ON (contrat.ID_PUBLICATION=pub.ID_PUBLICATION)
    WHERE
    contrat.ID_CONTRAT = :0 and dep.DATE_DEPOT_DECLA < to_date( ':1' ,'YYYY/MM/DD')

    GROUP BY
    pub.LIB_TITRE,
    contrat.id_contrat,
    NVL(dp.NUM_PARUTION_DECLA,dp.NUM_PARUTION_CONST),
    dep.id_depot,
    dep.DATE_DEPOT_DECLA,
    drl.STATUT_DEPOT
    ORDER BY dep.DATE_DEPOT_DECLA DESC,NVL(dp.NUM_PARUTION_DECLA,dp.NUM_PARUTION_CONST) DESC
) where numLigne <=30;
";


$toto = $this->executeQueries($sQuery, array($idContrat,$dateDecla));
$aResultSet = $this->getAllRows();
var_dump($toto);
```